# Is there a way to make a solid div with 3 transparent boxes in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I've seen coding on here for one transparent box inside a div, 
but not for multiple and I'm having issues getting anything to work right.. 
I have one outter div that holds 3 boxes inside to the left, center & right with a border. 
I want those 3 boxes to be transparent with opacity 0.3 all the way thru to the main background.. 
Is it possible to accomplish this with the simple coding I'm using without `FlexBox` or `JavaScript`?? 
 
How can I make the main div solid with 3 transparent boxes in it?? 
Here is my coding and a image..

```css
body {
background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3");
background-color: #ffffff;
background-position: top center;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
height:600px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-attachment:fixed;
z-index: 9999px;  
}

main {
background: #336699;
width:90%;
height:600px;
margin: 300px 0px 0px 100px;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 1;
}
  
.divl {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
float:left;
text-align:center;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divr {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
float:right;
text-align:center;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divc {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
text-align:center;
text-align:center;
width: 50%;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
margin:auto;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}
text-align:center;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divr {
background: transparent;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
float:right;
text-align:center;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divc {
background: transparent;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
text-align:center;
text-align:center;
width: 50%;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
margin:auto;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <main>
     <div class="divl">Left <br> Make This Box Transparent..</div>
     <div class="divr">Right <br> Make This Box Transparent..</div>
     <div class="divc">Center <br> Make This Box Transparent..</div>
    </main>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: As long as `<main>` itself is not transparant, trying to make the divs transparant will be a futile effort...

Comment: Why did you set the `z-index` of body to 9999?

Comment: I'm going to make the background stay fixed when I scroll.. I'll have multiple images on the fixed background and the top images will scroll.. I just wasnt done with the rest of the coding Lol.. My bad..

Comment: Is there a way to make the main div solid with 3 transparent holes in it??

Comment: Never ever use Java to work with layout. Be careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope that's what you need. When you specify background-attachment: fixed it goes relative to window not to parent block.

```css
body {
background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3");
background-color: #ffffff;
background-position: top center;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
height:600px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-attachment:fixed;
z-index: 9999px;  
}

main {
background: #336699;
width:90%;
height:600px;
margin: 300px 0px 0px 100px;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 1;
}
  
.divl {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
float:left;
text-align:center;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divr {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
float:right;
text-align:center;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divc {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
text-align:center;
text-align:center;
width: 50%;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
margin:auto;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <main>
     <div class="divl">Left <br> Make This Box Transparent..</div>
     <div class="divr">Right <br> Make This Box Transparent..</div>
     <div class="divc">Center <br> Make This Box Transparent..</div>
    </main>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @NICK then mark it as a right answer, please. Thus, you point users to right answer and tip the one who answered to the question.

Comment: How Do I Make Sure You Get Credit For Answering It?? I Click Answer And It Answers It But Dont Link Me To You..

Comment: The mark icon beneath the votes. (left top corner of the answer block). When you hover it it becomes green. The answer you click it on becomes "right"

Comment: Is There A Way I Can Make It So I Don't Have To Add A Photo In Each Section? I'm Doing The Parallax Web Theme..

Comment: @NICK perhaps. Anyway for the browser it's like one image. It's downloaded once and being reused as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your main html tag has a solid color assigned to it, so your three divs are transparent but the one holding them "main" is not. You will need to assign transparency to main or remove the solid background.

```
main {
    /*background: #336699; remove this to see the background image */
    background: #33669947; /*optionally use hex to add transparency*/
    width:90%;
    height:600px;
    margin: 300px 0px 0px 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
   }
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the main div solid with 3 transparent holes in it?? left center and right..

Comment: @NICK not by using HTML + CSS, You probably just want to make a border with the color you want on your 3 inner divs.

Comment: @NICK. if you can post an example of the effect you are trying to achieve I can help you more.

Comment: I posted a picture of the example I want.. Just want to make the main dive solid with 3 transparent boxes in it..

Comment: @NICK right the problem is that if your main div is solid and your inner divs are transparent you will only see through the inner divs to the main div, you cannot see through the main div because it is solid.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3");
background-color: #ffffff;
background-position: top center;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
height:600px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-attachment:fixed;
z-index: 9999px;  
}

main {
background: #336699;
width:90%;
height:600px;
margin: 300px 0px 0px 100px;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 1;
}
  
.divl {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
float:left;
text-align:center;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divr {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
float:right;
text-align:center;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divc {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.3;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
text-align:center;
text-align:center;
width: 50%;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
margin:auto;
padding: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <main>
     <div class="divl">Left <br> Make This Box Transparent..</div>
     <div class="divr">Right <br> Make This Box Transparent..</div>
     <div class="divc">Center <br> Make This Box Transparent..</div>
    </main>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```